# Error Plotting: Data Must Be 1-Dimensional

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

I am testing this code.

```
prod_count = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['product_name'])['order_id'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20))
plt.figure()
sns.barplot(prod_count.index, prod_count.values, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('Counts of Top Products Sold')
plt.ylabel('Number of Products', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Products', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

My `product_count.index` looks like this:

```
Index(['Banana', 'Bag of Organic Bananas', 'Organic Strawberries',
       'Organic Hass Avocado', 'Limes', 'Strawberries', 'Organic Baby Spinach',
       'Large Lemon', 'Organic Raspberries', 'Organic Garlic',
       'Organic Avocado', 'Organic Yellow Onion', 'Organic Zucchini',
       'Organic Gala Apples', 'Cucumber Kirby', 'Organic Red Onion',
       'Organic Whole Milk', '100% Whole Wheat Bread', 'Organic Cilantro',
       'Apple Honeycrisp Organic'],
      dtype='object', name='product_name')
```

My `prod_count.values` looks like this:

```
array([[48],
       [34],
       [25],
       [23],
       [18],
       [17],
       [17],
       [17],
       [13],
       [12],
       [11],
       [11],
       [11],
       [10],
       [ 9],
       [ 9],
       [ 9],
       [ 9],
       [ 8],
       [ 8]], dtype=int64)
```

I'm not sure why the field name says 'order_id' when I am doing an order count, but the dataframe should be like this.

```
product_name                        order_id
Banana  48
Bag of Organic Bananas  34
Organic Strawberries    25
Organic Hass Avocado    23
Limes   18
Strawberries    17
Organic Baby Spinach    17
Large Lemon 17
Organic Raspberries 13
Organic Garlic  12
Organic Avocado 11
Organic Yellow Onion    11
Organic Zucchini    11
Organic Gala Apples 10
Cucumber Kirby  9
Organic Red Onion   9
Organic Whole Milk  9
100% Whole Wheat Bread  9
Organic Cilantro    8
Apple Honeycrisp Organic    8
```

And, the chart should look like this.

[image]

FYI, I found the plotting code on this site.

https://www.kaggle.com/tejainece/seaborn-barplot-and-pandas-value-counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are trying to plot a pd.DataFrame (prod_count is a dataframe) which is not 1-dimensional. So you want to access the values from 'order_id' column from that dataframe. So try this instead :
`sns.barplot(prod_count.index, prod_count['order_id'].values, alpha=0.8)`

Comment: Oh, now I see how it works.  I just learned about this concept earlier today.  Thanks for the help here, Simon.